# Oracle) Insert multiple rows with one fixed value

Tags: sql, oracle

I'd like to insert these values in the following fashion:

```
insert into table (name, action-id) values ('user', select action from actions where name='user2');
```

The result being:

Inserts along the line of, `('user', 1) ('user', 2) ('user', 3)`

I'm noticing this isn't correct sql.
How would I go about accomplishing this?

note)

```
select action from actions where name='user2'
```

would return: (1, 2, 3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a loop:

```
BEGIN 

    FOR x IN (select action from actions where name='user2') LOOP

         insert into table (name, action-id) values ('user', x.action)

    END LOOP;
END;
```

or you could use the [INSERT/SELECT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/insert-select.html) syntax:

```
INSERT INTO table (name, action-id)
  SELECT 'user', action
  FROM actions WHERE name='user2';
```

Comment: Thanks, works great!
Nice how you've made the comparison to the loop as well.

Answer (score 2):

Add the fixed value as a column in your query, and use insert-select instead of insert-values:

```
insert into table (name, action-id)
select 'user', action from actions where name='user2';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Or can be done by procedure 
Create that procedure and run it
create or replace procedure set_action
```

as
   cursor c1 is
   select * from user;
   person c1%rowtype;
   username varchar(8);
   begin
    username:='user';
    for person in c1 loop
    insert into table(name,action-id)
    values (username,person.action);
    end loop;
   end;
   It can be run by execute set_action;

Comment: That's quite a lot of overhead and complexity for something that easily be done in plain SQL...

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
create table testing(col1 varchar2(10), col2 varchar2(10));
create table testing2(col1 varchar2(10), col2 varchar2(10));
create table testing3(col1 varchar2(10), col2 int);
insert into testing2 (col1, col2) values ('test2_col1', 'test2_col2');
insert into testing3(col1, col2) values ('steve', 1);
insert into testing3(col1, col2) values ('brad', 2);
insert into testing3(col1, col2) values ('chad', 3);
insert into testing3(col1, col2) values ('nick', 1);
insert into testing(col1, col2)
  (select col1 ,(select col2 from testing2) from testing3); -- inserts 4 rows
```

And finally:

`select * from testing;
steve   test2_col2
brad    test2_col2
chad    test2_col2
nick    test2_col2`