# pl/sql insert from select

Tags: sql, oracle, select, plsql, sql-insert

I have tow tables:

- `table1` with 5 columns
- `table2` with 4 columns

I want to copy the data from `table2` to `table1`.

In `table1` I have column with default value, let's say column2 ='default'

How i do it in PL/SQL?

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure?

Comment: This is what the school want

Comment: You should _always_ show what you tired yourself.  _ESPECIALLY_ when the question is a homework assignment.

Comment: "I have column with default value" - does that mean you have a default already defined for the column as part of the table definition; or that you want the insert to use a fixed value for that column? Showing the table definitions, sample data and expected results for that data in your question (by [editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62640141/edit))  would be helpful.

Comment: Yes , insert a fixed value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle) Insert multiple rows with one fixed value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26164455/oracle-insert-multiple-rows-with-one-fixed-value)

Answer (score 0):

You can `insert` and enumerate the target columns. The idea is:

```
insert into table1(col1, col3, col4, col5)
select col1, col2, col3, col4 from table2
```

The "additional" column of `table1` (I assumed `col2`) is not part of the list of columns to insert into - so Oracle will happily use the configured default value.

Comment: Thank you , but i didn't get the second part how i configure default value ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `constant` value for the `col2` as follows:

```
insert into table1(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
select col1, 'default', col2, col3, col4 from table2;
```